# How can I connect my ui form to mysql and insert data using the ui form?

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to connect my PyQt form to MySql database. I tried to use the following codes to connect to the database and insert data but it doesn't work. Anything that I missed? I'm getting an attribute error `__enter__`. what does this mean?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore    import pyqtSlot
import mysql.connector as mdb

from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btnAdd.clicked.connect(self.InsertData)

    @pyqtSlot() 
    def InsertData(self):
        con = mdb.connect(user='root', password='password101',
                        host='localhost', database='sample_sys')
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()

            cur.execute("INSERT INTO name_info(name, age)"
                        "VALUES('%s','%s')" % (''.join(self.le_name.text()),
                                                ''.join(self.le_age.text())))
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Connection", "Data Inserted Successfully")
            self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow()

    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you could show the complete error message.

Comment: Please don't string format values to queries. Use your DB-API driver's placeholders, which removes the need to manually quote, among other things. In case of mysql.connector they're `%s`, which can be a bit confusing. Pass the arguments in a sequence in the 2nd positional argument of `execute()`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html for details.

Comment: The error means that something you're trying to use in a with-statement is not a context manager. Maybe the `con`? It's hard to say without the proper traceback.

Comment: here's the complete error message:

runfile('/Users/anthonygaupo/Desktop/Sample/sample_sys/function.py', wdir='/Users/anthonygaupo/Desktop/Sample/sample_sys')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/anthonygaupo/Desktop/Sample/sample_sys/function.py", line 30, in InsertData
    with con:

AttributeError: __enter__

Comment: @IljaEverilä yes, the error say its with the InsertData with con.

Comment: thank you all! I just installed mysqldb. and the codes worked to me. thanks to your replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using MySQLdb, everything works.
MySQLdb is an thread-compatible interface to the popular MySQL database server that provides the Python database API.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore    import pyqtSlot
#import mysql.connector as mdb
import MySQLdb as mdb

from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.button.setEnabled(False)

        self.initWindow()

    def initWindow(self):
        self.lineedit1.setPlaceholderText('Please enter your name')
        self.lineedit2.setPlaceholderText('Please enter your email')
        self.lineedit3.setPlaceholderText('Please enter your phone number')

        self.lineedit1.textChanged.connect(self.newText)
        self.lineedit2.textChanged.connect(self.newText)
        self.lineedit3.textChanged.connect(self.newText)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.InsertData)

    @pyqtSlot() 
    def InsertData(self):
        con = mdb.connect(host="localhost",user="user", passwd="password",db="testdb")

        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()  
            cur.execute('''INSERT INTO pyqt5data(name, email, phone)
                           VALUES (%s, %s, %s)''', 
                           ( self.lineedit1.text(),
                             self.lineedit2.text(),
                             self.lineedit3.text() )
                       )            
            cur.close()

            QMessageBox.information(self, "Connection", "Data Inserted Successfully")

        self.lineedit1.setText('')
        self.lineedit2.setText('')
        self.lineedit3.setText('')
        self.initWindow()       

    def newText(self):
        if self.lineedit1.text() and self.lineedit2.text() and self.lineedit3.text():
            self.button.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.button.setEnabled(False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

mainwindow.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mainwindow.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.10
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 300)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 81, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineedit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineedit1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 30, 171, 20))
        self.lineedit1.setObjectName("lineedit1")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 70, 81, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 110, 81, 16))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.lineedit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineedit2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 70, 171, 20))
        self.lineedit2.setObjectName("lineedit2")
        self.lineedit3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineedit3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 110, 171, 20))
        self.lineedit3.setObjectName("lineedit3")
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(94, 170, 181, 23))
        self.button.setObjectName("button")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 400, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Name"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Email"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Phone"))
        self.button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "INSERT"))
```

[image]

Comment: I was having trouble installing the mysqldb. thats why i use the mysql.connector. is mysqldb better than the python connector? Thank you!

Comment: Hi sir, I was able to install mysql client already alongside mysqldb module. Your codes worked already to me. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Sir, id like to do this: after i click ok button after successfully inserted data, id like to clear the form and disable the buttons. and enable it again once the form is filled up.

Comment: Thank you very much sir for the help! The cur.close() is already the code to close the db connection right?

Comment: cur.close()  Closes the cursor.  If you are using server-side cursors, it is very important to close the cursor when you are done with it and before creating a new one.

Comment: with the code above, were we able close the connection to the database?